# vba control open file dialog

Tags: vba, excel, filedialog

I'm currently working on Excel macro which controls webpage. I've problem with interacting with open file dialog. It can be control by simply pasting file path and hitting enter. I've tried to `SendKeys` but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
Sub controlFileDialog()
    MyFilePath = Range("j3") & "\" & Number & ".xml"
    SendKeys (MyFilePath)
    SendKeys ("~")
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of Number, I don't see it defined in your code. How did you qualify your MyFilePath, as string? Does Range("j3") reflect the correct workbook and worksheet. It is good practice to explicitly define the workbook and worksheet where this value originates.

Comment: sorry, I didn't want to copy all sub, becouse it's masive. MyFilePath is correct. I've check it by bringing it up  with Msgbox.

Comment: Also what means "doesn't work" does it give an error, it does something unexpected, it does nothing at all? It might be good to implement waiting in your first sendkeys like this: Sendkeys(MyFilePath,true) to force the macro to wait execution of the next line untill all characters are typed.

Comment: No it doesn't give any. Macro makes every step properly until it opens file dialog and then do nothing. When I try to debugg it I can't hit single step while file dialog is open, and when i close it and hit F8 it obviusly sends MyFilePath to Code.

Comment: Can you show us the code that opens the file dialog?

Comment: It's to long so I've to share it with that link https://paste.ofcode.org/32xkZZJq5K73ZfMJXwcPbxK

Comment: I've made VBScript and macro is launching it automaticly before opening file dialog. Script containt sleep function, then set focus on active file dialog and send proper keys.

Comment: Please share the code you built as an answer so in the future people can benefit from your research.